# Set property for a specific length of time in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm getting to grips with Xamarin.Forms and I'm trying to display some content for a specific amount of time e.g. 10 seconds and then reverting the content back to what it was.

I use a bool property `DisplayNotification` to bind to the IsVisible property.

xaml code:

```
<ContentView Style="{DynamicResource headerContentViewStyle}" IsVisible="{Binding DisplayNotification, Converter={StaticResource inverter}}">
    <Label Style="{DynamicResource labelHeaderStyle}" Text="{Binding SelectTaskHeader}" />
</ContentView>
<ContentView Style="{DynamicResource headerContentViewStyle}" IsVisible="{Binding DisplayNotification}">
    <Label Style="{DynamicResource labelHeaderStyle}" Text="{Binding SelectAltTaskHeader}" />
</ContentView>
```

view model code:

```
private bool _showNotification;

public bool DisplayNotification
{
    get { return _showNotification; }
    set => this.SetProperty(ref this._showNotification, value);
}
```

So wherever in the view model the `DisplayNotification = true`, the `SelectAltTaskHeader` is displayed and wherever `DisplayNotification = false`, the `SelectTaskHeader` is displayed.

I want to be able to set DisplayNotification = true for a specific amount of time e.g. 10 seconds.

I'm using Xamarin.Forms version="2.3.3.180".

Comment: Have you looked at Device.StartTimer?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.starttimer?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: don't use Device.StartTimer, use System.Timers

Comment: @Jason reason being?

Comment: Device.StartTimer was introduced with Forms 1.x because normal .NET timers were not available in a PCL project.  Now that .NET Standard has replaced PCL you can just use the standard Timers classes, which are more flexible

Comment: Ah, I'm using Forms version="2.3.3.180" and the Timers class doesn't look like it's available.

Comment: That's a very old version of Forms. If you're trying to learn it, I would suggest using the latest version, or as close as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a timer, as has been suggested, but I think I'd likely just use async/await. You could do this:

```
async Task DisplayNotifcationForTenSeconds()
{
    DisplayNotification = true;
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    DisplayNotification = false;
}
```